# NextJS Dynamic Loading of Components

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, sanity

I am using Sanity.io as a storage system, and I want to dynamically load components based on the content type. In the builder, each content element is assigned a "_type" value (such as "Hero" or "Quote"), and there is a corresponding component with props for each type.

Since a content manager may use an unknown number of content elements in any order, I need to use a function called "getDynamicComponent" to call the appropriate component for each element. The component then displays the content inside it. However, I am encountering an error when using Next/Image or PortableText components, which I need to resolve.

```
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
error - TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')
    at stringify (<anonymous>)
error - TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useMemo')
    at stringify (<anonymous>)
```

```js
import { groq } from 'next-sanity'
import createClient from '../../lib/sanity.client'
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'
import { RichtextComponents } from '@/components/RichText'
import { PortableText } from '@portabletext/react'
import { ComponentType } from 'react';

const pageQuery = groq`
    *[_type == "page_documents" && hidden == false] {
        ...,
        pageBuilder[]->
    } | order(_createdAt desc)
`

const getDynamicComponent = (type: string): ComponentType<any> => {
    let DynamicComponent;
    try {
        DynamicComponent = dynamic(() => import(`@/components/${type}`), {
            ssr: false,
            loading: () => <p>Loading...</p>,
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        DynamicComponent = dynamic(() => import(`@/components/MissingComponent`), {
            ssr: false,
            loading: () => <p>Loading...</p>,
        });
    }
    return DynamicComponent;
};

const Home = async () => {
    const pages = await createClient.fetch(pageQuery)

    return (
        <>
            {
                pages.map((page: Page, index: number) => {
                    return (
                        <>
                            <div key={index}>
                                <>
                                    {
                                        page.pageBuilder.map((builder: any, index: number) => {
                                            // builder._type === 'Hero'
                                            const DynamicComponent = getDynamicComponent(builder._type);
                                            return (
                                                <div key={index}>
                                                    <PortableText
                                                        value={builder.body}
                                                        components={RichtextComponents}
                                                    /> {/* This is working */}

                                                    {DynamicComponent && <DynamicComponent {...builder} />}
                                                </div>
                                            );
                                        })
                                    }
                                </>
                            </div>
                        </>
                    )
                })
            }
        </>
    )
}

export default Home
```

Hero Component:
The specified props are not 'null' or 'undefined'. That shouldn't be the issue. I can output the individual properties, but it doesn't work when I use something like Next/Image.

```js
import { PortableText } from '@portabletext/react';
import Image from 'next/image';
import urlFor from '../lib/urlFor'
import { RichtextComponents } from './RichText';


const Hero = (props: any) => {
    return (
        <>
            <div>{props.title}</div> {/* This is working */}
            {urlFor(props.mainImage).url()} <br /> {/* This is working */}
            {
                props.body.map((x: any, index: number) => {
                    return (
                        <>
                            { x.style } {/* This is working */}
                        </>
                    )
                })
            }
            {/* 
            FOLLOWING IS NOT WORKING!

            <div>
                {
                    props.mainImage && urlFor(props.mainImage).url() &&
                    <Image
                        className="object-cover object-left lg:object-center"
                        src={urlFor(props.mainImage).url()}
                        alt={props.title}
                        fill
                    />
                }
            </div>

            {props.body &&
                <PortableText
                    // Pass in block content straight from Sanity.io
                    value={props.body}
                    components={RichtextComponents}
                />
            } */}
        </>
    )
}

export default Hero
```

```
"dependencies": {
    "@portabletext/react": "^2.0.2",
    "@sanity/client": "^5.2.2",
    "@sanity/vision": "^3.0.0",
    "@types/node": "18.15.0",
    "@types/react": "18.0.28",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.11",
    "eslint": "8.36.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.2.4",
    "next": "13.2.4",
    "next-sanity": "^4.1.5",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-is": "^18.2.0",
    "sanity": "^3.0.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.0",
    "typescript": "4.9.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@sanity/eslint-config-studio": "^2.0.1",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.25",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.26",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
    "eslint": "^8.6.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.21",
    "prettier": "^2.8.4",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.7"
  }
```

Is this the correct approach, or is there a better way to achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to rafaelalmeidatk#7126 on discord.gg/nextjs
I'm totally fine with this solution

```js
import { groq } from 'next-sanity'
import createClient from '../../lib/sanity.client'
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'
import { ComponentType } from 'react';


interface SanityComponents<T> {
    [key: string]: ComponentType<T>;
}

const sanityComponents: SanityComponents<any> = {
    Hero: dynamic(() => import('@/components/Hero')),
    // ...
};

const pageQuery = groq`
    *[_type == "page_documents" && hidden == false] {
        ...,
        pageBuilder[]->
    } | order(_createdAt desc)
`

const Home = async () => {
    const pages = await createClient.fetch(pageQuery)

    return (
        <>
            {
                pages.map((page: Page, index: number) => {
                    return (
                        <div key={index}>
                            {
                                page.pageBuilder.map((builder: any, index: number) => {
                                    const SanityComponent = sanityComponents[builder._type]
                                    return <SanityComponent {...builder} key={builder._id} />
                                })
                            }
                        </div>
                    )
                })
            }
        </>
    )
}

export default Home
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).